# Как получить обратную связь после звонка?

Tags: java, android

Я вызываю ACTION_CALL. В документах написано, что никакого ответа не будет.

Проверил, в OnActivityResult ответ сразу приходит 0, до вызова звонка даже. В общем, есть логика как сделать это все-таки? Может через BroadCastReceiver или как-нибудь еще.

Comment: Совет - когда вы вызываете интентом активити другого приложения, лучше не ориентируйтесь на возвращаемый код в onActivityResult.  Нет никаких гарантий, что вам придет именно то что вы ожидаете. Там всё зависит от реализации конкретного приложения. К примеру приложение Почта на мейзу и сяоми могут вам возвращать разные ответы на одно и тоже действие

Comment: @SviatVolkov, Спасибо за совет). Задачу же надо как то решать. Каким образом решаются такого рода задачи?

Answer (score 2):

Можно через BroadCast, попробуйте так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private PhoneStateListener myPhoneListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            Log.d("...", "state: " + state);
            Log.d("...", "incomingNumber: " + incomingNumber);
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephonyManager != null) telephonyManager.listen(myPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (telephonyManager != null) telephonyManager.listen(myPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы мой спаситель)).

Но onResume и pause срабыаватеют даже когда я просто сворачиваю и разворчаиваю окно.

Поэтому мне надо создать слушатель когда я нажимаю на кнопку Вызова, котроый вызывает ACITON_CALL?

А onPuase убрать верно?

Comment: Ну это уже зависит от ваших нужд, хоть в сервис выносите. Я же не знаю что вы там делаете, просто не забывайте отписывать листенер, иначе колбеки будут продолжать приходить, а это не очень хорошо. Попробуйте вначале в onDestroy, но знайте что нет гарантии что он вызовется

Comment: А почему все так глючит? я получаю ответ `CALL_STATE_IDLE` `CALL_STATE_IDLE` `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`.

А после окончания звонка `CALL_STATE_IDLE`. Я тестирую на эмуляторе

Comment: Потому что у вас в 1 колбек приходят все состояния, вам их нужно обрабатывать для этого и существует параметр state, я вам в логах специально указал

Comment: Вообще - то в логах должно хоть что - то приходить. Я звоню. в логах вижу. state 0, state 0, state 2. Сбрасываю звонок state 0.

И как по вашему можно тут что - то понять?

Обрабатывать звонки можно было. Если бы
было бы типо state 0 state 20 state 30  state 50. То тогда еще что - то можно было сделать. А тут каша.

Типо каждый state уникальный для каждого действия. А тут каша

`incomingNumber` вообще всегда пустой.